Foundations and contradictions of Scholze's work: the category of presentable infinity categories contains itself
Preface: I am not an expert in the work of Scholze, or anything for that matter.
Question
Has Scholze stated what axioms he is using to develop his theory of motives and analytic geometry. In the following talk he seems to produce a contradiction to both ZFC and NBG;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1lChD8fuGc
He seems to draw on the work of Lurie for his foundations, however Lurie doesnt make clear what his categorical foundations are in "Higher Topos Theory" or "Higher Algebra" so I'm not sure that you can import foundations from his work. Indeed, maybe this question is more aptly named, "Has Lurie specified his axioms?". Lurie references Mac Lane who seems to use universes, however Scholze says something along the lines of avoiding universes, but also talks about categories containing the category of all sets, which sounds like NBG.
I will provide a brief explanation of the contradiction as I see it, which occurs  at the 30 min and 30 sec mark.
The statement
First we let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal. Scholze states that for the purposes of his theory we may as well take $\kappa = \aleph_1$. He then defines the following category
$$\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa = \{\kappa-\text{compactly generated presentable }(\infty, 1)-\text{cats}, \text{colimit and }\kappa-\text{compact object preserving functors}\}$$
He then states that
$$\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa \in \mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$$
which should properly mean that it is an object in the category
$$\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa)$$
Why this shouldn't be allowed
In NBG to be an element of something is to be a set, and therefore we reduce to the case of ZFC. In ZFC no set can contain itself by the axiom of regularity / well-foundedness.
It seems that there must be something tricky going on here using the fact that $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ is a category and so as a set it is more than just its collection of objects. But this seems fraught with danger. It really seems to depend on how you set up category theory, not just ZFC+I vs NBG, but which particular sets you define categories to be etc.
A relevant thread that upon an amateurs perusal seems to support that this conclusion cannot be is; Is the $\infty$-category of presentable $\infty$-categories presentable?
Another relevant thread (that I havent had time to look through carefully yet) is Scholze's post; Reflection principle vs universes
Thanks.

You will find that the precise axiom system does not matter, ultimately. If this relied on the choice of ZFC vs NBG then it would be bad category theory. You should also be aware that a presentation given in a talk is not quite so rigorous as the actual written version. Scholze is actually rather sensitive to foundational choices, which is why condensed sets don't assume the existence of inaccessibles, like pyknotic sets do. I hope he comes along and clarifies what he meant in that talk.

Also, there are other set theories, equivalent in strength to ZFC etc, where no elements of sets are themselves sets, and such foundations can be used to set up all the category theory in the world. So any argument about sets containing themselves or not is moot, in those foundations. Any actual contradiction, should there be one that (and I don't think there will be), will not depend on the axiom of regularity.

The statement is indeed mysterious, and I would also like an answer to this question as to how the apparent contradiction is resolved.

In another context, a similar apparent contradiction occurs on the top of page 28 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.2204. In that paper, it is stated that $\mathfrak{Top}^{\text{ét}}\infty/\mathcal E\cong \mathcal E$ which, given that $\mathcal E\in\mathfrak{Top}^{\text{ét}}\infty/\mathcal E$, seems to imply $\mathcal E\in  \mathcal E$.

One way to make sense of this is to recall that  $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ can either be presented as the (very large) category of $\kappa$-presentable (large) categories and cocontinuous functors preserving $\kappa$-compact objects or as the large category of $\kappa$-cocomplete small categories and $\kappa$-cocontinuous functors. If we take the first occurrence of $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ to be the latter and the second to be the former, this is easier to interpret. Technically, it amounts to the claim that $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ is $\kappa$-compactly generated which is (remarkably) true.

@DavidRoberts: "there are other set theories, equivalent in strength to ZFC etc, where no elements of sets are themselves sets" -- could you give any links, this sounds interesting. Indeed Scholtze is certainly more well versed than I am, so im curious to see why this isnt as bad as it looks.

$\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa\in \mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ is a true and completely harmless statement, even if it cannot directly be expressed in classical set-theoretic foundations. The essential issue is not one of size (there are standard ways to work with "large" objects in set-theoretic foundations), but it is that $\infty$-groupoids/types/anima are more general than sets, and the axiom of regularity simply does not hold for them. A "set-theoretic translation" of the statement would look like $A\in\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ and $A\simeq \mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$, which does not violate regularity.

@Rilem cf https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory and references there

@MarcHoyois I see, much like Andres response you can avoid the problem of regularity by simply looking at objects only up to isomorphism. This makes sense. I wonder what foundations you have in mind when you say something like "anima are more general than sets, and the axiom of regularity simply does not hold for them", I would like to free myself of the mental shackle of ZFC.

I don't have any formal foundations in mind.

@MarcHoyois I see that including categories that are isomorphic to $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ makes that statement sensible, but one would think that this would still imply that all the categories isomorphic to this one are still in there. Hence if $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa \cong A \in \mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ then we could conclude $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa\in \mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$. One way to get around this and have the statement be true is to explicitly define $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ to contain things isomorphic but not equal to itself?

@Rilem: freeing yourself from the “shackles of ZFC here” doesn’t require moving to an alternate foundation. The apparent conflict comes from reading this $\in$ as the literal membership relation of ZFC: that relation is not isomorphism/equivalence-invariant, which is essential for how ZFC encodes mathematical objects, but means that in mathematical practice, where we’re usually working with objects “structurally” (i.e. up to isomorphism/equivalence), it’s not usually quite the relation we want on abstract sets/collections/categories/etc.

@Rilem: Your last comment here is addressed in my answer.

@Rilem It's not isomorphism of categories, but equivalence. And a large category (i.e. one with a proper class of objects) can be equivalent to a small one (one with  a set of objects and a set of morphisms between any pair of objects).

@DavidRoberts Thank you, together with Peters answer this makes sense. I will have to think more carefully to fully digest this.

We had some discussion of this point on the category theory zulip a few years ago.

A toy example of the same phenomenon: say a category is contractible if it’s equivalent to the terminal category (i.e. codiscrete and inhabited).  Let $\newcommand{\E}{\mathcal{E}}\E$ be the category of contractible categories, and functors between them up to natural isomorphism.  Then $\E$ is a contractible category; so $\E \in \E$?
Reading over everything carefully, to form $\E$ at all, we must have meant it was the category of small contractible categories (or some other standard way to handle size issues). Then $\E$ is not small, so it’s not literally an object of itself, but it is essentially small, so it is an object of itself up to equivalence.  So $\E \in \E$ is true up to equivalence: there is some $\E' \in \E$ and equivalence $\E' \simeq \E$.
I understand the situation with Scholze’s $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ (and the Lurie example mentioned by André Henriques in comments) as exactly analogous. $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ itself must be formally defined with some size restriction on its objects; that will prevent it from being literally an object of itself.  However, it’s compactly generated, so up to equivalence, it is an element of itself.

There is a subtle difference between this example and the $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ situation: $\mathcal E$ is really a 2-category of 1-categories, and to contemplate the statement $\mathcal E\in\mathcal E$ you have to allow yourself to view $\mathcal E$ as a 3-category of 2-categories (and then as a 4-category, a 5-category, etc.). So the actual failure of regularity only occurs if you go all the way to $\infty$-categories. As I expressed in my comment to the OP, the point is not one of size but is really about the nature of $\infty$-things.

@MarcHoyois: I don’t entirely agree, unless I’m misunderstanding you.  I was careful to make $\mathcal{E}$ into a 1-category by modding out its morphisms (leaving its class of objects unchanged) — so it really is a 1-category of 1-categories.  I think the apparent conflict with regularity doesn’t come from the $\infty$-nature, but from working with objects structurally rather than in coding-dependent ways.  Of course, these aren’t unrelated, since working fully structurally inevitably pushes one towards infinity-categorical language, and possibly infinity-categorical foundations…

@MarcHoyois: Of course, the toy example can be taken directly in the infinity-categorical world as well — take the infinity-category of all contractible (small) infinity-categories.  But I think the original version shows that the same phenomenon does already occur at the 1-categorical level.

One potential way (as you know, Peter) to think about the category at hand is to consider the objects to be the small categories that generate the presentable categories, but then the morphisms to be whatever they need to be to recover the functors between the corresponding Ind-categories. Then the large category of these things is the appropriate Ind-completion of one of its objects. :-)

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I think you did misunderstand my comment. My point is that statements like $\mathcal E\in\mathcal E$ and $\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa\in\mathrm{Pr}^\kappa$ can be be regarded as literally true in the $\infty$-world, but without the concept of anima they can only be true up to something (as in your post/comments).

@MarcHoyois: I agree with the first half of that point, that we can and should see statements as $\mathcal{E} \in \mathcal{E}$ to be literally true — what I’m suggesting (in comments on the question, I guess I didn’t say it in my answer!) is that this doesn’t necessarily require “move to the $\infty$-world”, but just the more general “take $\in$ to be something other than material-set-theoretic $\in$”, and that this is very natural in several other settings beside the $\infty$-world.

@MarcHoyois "can be be regarded as literally true" sounds like an oxymoron.

Perhaps it is useful to go a step further like we do in set theory, and make a hierarchy of distinctions of sizes. Rather than merely distinguishing small vs. large categories, one might speak of “categories of rank $<\alpha$” for ordinals $\alpha$.

@MonroeEskew: When dealing with questions where size issues matter, category theorists (or users of category theory) and type theorists do use hierarchies of size distinctions — e.g. “$\kappa$-small categories” for cardinals $\kappa$.  But “rank” isn’t used, assuming you mean something analogous to set-theoretic rank — that’s important in the structure of the cumulative hierarchy, but much less meaningful when considering sets (or objects built from them) as mathematical structures. [cont’d]

As I say in comments on Tim’s answer, I think the apparent analogy with set-theoretic membership here is really erroneous — they are two fundamentally different senses of “$\in$”, that one shouldn’t expect to behave in comparable ways.

Pardon my ignorance.  But the deeper reason behind my comment is that keeping track of cardinality is less fine than keeping track of "when things are born", which can be useful in more complicated recursive constructions where a seemingly circular definition is made to make sense because of some hierarchical birthday structure, and cardinality doesn't provide enough structure to work with.

@MonroeEskew: Absolutely — as you say, rank is useful for tracking elements within a structure that is iteratively/recursively generated in some sense.  The assumption that the entire mathematical universe is iteratively generated in such a way — the cumulative hierarchy — is one of the very characteristic features of ZF(C) and closely-related theories.  Most other foundations I know don’t make this assumption, and I know virtually nowhere it occurs outside  topics specifically involving the metatheory of ZF(C)-like theories.  (Cf. this question)

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I agree that even classically there is no harm in saying $\mathcal E\in\mathcal E$, but ultimately this is because there exists a univalent setting where it is actually true (univalence is what I meant above by "the nature of $\infty$-things"). Classical category theory emulates univalence, but only in the $\infty$-world does it actually hold. Anyway, I don't want to keep trying to make this point, because it seems that everyone else here is discussing things completely orthogonal to it.

Putting the "picture of the universe" aside, my main point is that set theory has developed a slew of sophisticated transfinite induction arguments for various applications.  They are not always about "$\in$-rank" directly but often build some other kind of hierarchy for the purpose at hand.  Maybe these ideas could be useful when category theory gets itself into such pickles as described in the OP, or elsewhere.  Anyway, as you know, in the context of Choice, the Foundation axiom is merely a simplifying assumption and doesn't add or subtract any structural information.

@MonroeEskew: The set-theoretic treasury of techniques for transfinite arguments is certainly good to promote (and it has been drawn on by category theorists at times) — but my point is that the apparent “pickle” in this question is a red herring; there’s no real problem here that needs resolving at all.  There’s a result which purely notationally looks like a failure of foundation, and OP has gotten spooked by that — an understandable first reaction — but as soon as one looks carefully at the statement and proof, there’s nothing really problematic, and not much connection to foundation.

I think Marc’s point is worth emphasizing. While it is true that universe restrictions are what save us from paradox, (so that technically what we have is $Pr_\kappa \in \Pr_\kappa’$ for $Pr_\kappa \neq Pr_\kappa’$) this phenomenon is still much stranger than the fact that the category of small categories is an object of the category of large categories, because the universe restrictions we end up doing do not affect the fact that $Pr_\kappa \simeq Pr_\kappa’$!
To be more precise, we have to be a bit gauche and actually specify our set-theoretic foundations. Let’s work in ZFC with a single universe $V_\lambda$ (where $\kappa \in V_\lambda$ is a regular cardinal). Define $Pr_\kappa$ to comprise those categories whose object sets are subsets of $V_\lambda$, morphism sets live in $V_\lambda$, and which satisfy the usual definition of $\kappa$-presentability in $V_\lambda$; a morphism in $Pr_\kappa$ is a left adjoint functor preserving $\kappa$-compact objects. [1] Then we get some dumb thing like $Pr_\kappa \in V_{\lambda+2} \setminus V_{\lambda+1}$, depending on exactly how categories are coded up in terms of ordered pairs and on exactly how ordered pairs are defined. Hence we don’t have $Pr_\kappa \in Ob(Pr_\kappa)$. Nevertheless, it turns out that the object set of $Pr_\kappa$ is only of size $\lambda$, and not of size $2^\lambda$. And the morphism sets of $Pr_\kappa$ are of size $<\lambda$. And indeed, $Pr_\kappa$ is equivalent to a category which is an element of $Pr_\kappa$.
I think the reason this seems bizarre to me is that when we make universe restrictions in category theory, we’re used to thinking of them as being restrictions on size. Most of the time when I say “small set”, I only care about the cardinality of the set, and not about whether it actually is an element of $V_\lambda$. But in order to avoid the paradox here, you have to remember that “small set” is not really just a restriction on the size of the set — it’s a restriction on the universe the set belongs to.
But really, for category-theoretic purposes, as Marc emphasizes, the universe-evasion maneuver was completely invisible. This is quite different from the paradox-evasion we do when we say “well, sure, I don’t actually want to work with a category with all products — just small ones”, where the set-theoretical size issues had a legitimate category-theoretic interpretation. On the contrary, I think the correct way to think about this category-theoretically is that $Pr_\kappa \in Pr_\kappa$ is literally true, and there’s something about not-containing-yourself which is not forbidden category-theoretically. I don’t pretend to have a fleshed out formal apparatus to back this up, but I’m pretty convinced that the fact that $Pr_\kappa \in Pr_\kappa$ is hinting at something new and interesting.
[1] I’m going to blithely pretend everything is a 1-category and not an $(\infty,1)$-category here, it’s not that important.

Also, another pointer to the discussion we had about this on the category theory zulip.

I think it’s also worth emphasizing that this is a fact which surprises many category theorists when they first learn it. My first reaction was “surely $Pr_\kappa \in Pr_{\kappa^+}$, but $Pr_\kappa \not \in Pr_\kappa$, right?”, and I suspect that’s most category theorists’ intuition, but nope! $\kappa$ stays the same. My second reaction was “wait, did I miss some unexpected universe-juggling which is necessary?” but nope, there’s no change in the notion of “small” here.

One thing that’s really fascinating is that the concluion “$Pr_\kappa \in Ob(Pr_\kappa’) \wedge Pr_\kappa \simeq Pr_\kappa’$” is not really surprising-looking category-theoretically. After all, we could be defining the objects of $Pr_\kappa’$ in some stupid,cheating, completely arbitrary way. What makes the whole thing interesting (in a hard-to-precisify way) is that the passage from $Pr_\kappa’$ back to $Pr_\kappa$ is the most standard, reflexive, invisible move possible.

Also — although $Pr_\kappa$ is an object of $Pr_\kappa$, it is not a $\kappa$-compact object. So the left adjoint functor $F : Set \to Pr_\kappa$ sending a point to $Pr_\kappa$ is a morphism in $Pr$ but not a morphism in $Pr_\kappa$. You might interpret this as saying that $Pr_\kappa$ is a “point” of $Pr_\kappa$, but not an “internal point” or something like that. (Here I’m thinking of left-adjoint functors from $Set$ as being like “points” because $Set$ is the unit of the Lurie tensor product on $Pr$ (which restricts to a tensor product on $Pr_\kappa$).)

This is a more interesting and much more subtle point than my answer. I think mine is the main answer of the question as written, but I guess this is behind the underlying discomfort that’s why OP asked it. Like Mike in the Zulip, I think the main subtlety is working out what (if anything) should really be surprising here.  Superficially, it looks analogous to Russellian paradoxical territory, but when one makes it precise (e.g. “$\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}\C$ is in the (essential) image of a certain functor $\C \to \mathrm{Cat}$”) it looks much less analogous to that, and not so surprising,

[cont’d] and also not equivalence-/representation-invariant in $\mathcal{C}$.  My feeling is that there is something genuinely surprising in $\mathrm{Pr}\kappa \in \mathrm{Pr}\kappa$, but I think the apparent analogy with Russellian paradoxes (or more structural universe-containing-itself paradoxes like Burali-Forti’s Girard’s) is erroneous, and merely notational — this is more about dimension-raising operations stabilising at $\infty$, and a size-increasing operation turning out to stabilise at the same time.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Here's a (vague) conjecture: there exists a strong form of linear logic (even "dependent linear type theory" to the extent that that exists -- or whatever kind of theory might strengthen linear logic in the way that dependent type theory with all the inductive types / univalence you want strengthens nonlinear logic) which has $Pr$ as a model (types are presentable categories, empty-context terms are objects therein; not sure exactly what nonempty context terms are), in which the $Pr_\kappa$ provide a hierarchy of universes, each satisfying $Pr_\kappa : Pr_\kappa$

I think if such a conjecture is true, then this fact is very closely related to Girard's paradox, no?

You are probably aware of this, not sure if it’s relevant: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/review-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/prospects-of-unlimited-category-theory-doing-what-remains-to-be-done/30916003E03AF3EAA5E9AB8D5D5D5C72

@TimCampion: Very nice — yes, I take the point, this issue does have more relation to Girard-paradox-type situations than I thought at first.  And that gives a bit of an answer to what’s surprising here.
